# ActiveRecord left_outer_joins on self-referencing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have self-referencing `Category` model with associated products.

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategories,
           class_name: 'Category',
           foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  has_many :products
  scope :main, -> { where(parent_id: nil) }
end
```

In order to get the count of subcategories and products for all main categories would like to perform a double left outer join.

This is how I do it without using `left_outer_joins` method.

```
Category.main
  .select('categories.*, COUNT(DISTINCT cats.id) as sub_count, COUNT(products.id) as prod_count')
  .joins('LEFT JOIN categories AS cats ON categories.id = cats.parent_id')
  .joins('LEFT JOIN products ON cats.id = products.category_id')
  .group('categories.name')
```

I wanted to do the same thing with `left_outer_joins` method as it is cleaner from the code perspective.

```
Category.main
  .select('categories.name, COUNT(DISTINCT subcategories_categories.id) as sub_count, COUNT(products.id) as prod_count')
  .left_joins(:subcategories, :products)
  .group('categories.name')
```

It outputs following query:

```
SELECT categories.name, COUNT(DISTINCT subcategories_categories.id) as sub_count, COUNT(products.id) as prod_count 
FROM "categories" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "categories" "subcategories_categories" ON "subcategories_categories"."parent_id" = "categories"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "products" ON "products"."category_id" = "categories"."id" 
WHERE "categories"."parent_id" IS NULL 
GROUP BY categories.name
```

As you can see the problem is in second `LEFT OUTER JOIN` because it refers to `categories` instead of `subcategories_categories`.

Is there any workaround with `left_outer_joins` for such scenarios?

Comment: AFAIK not really - you can pass lumps of SQL to the `joins` method... which is basically what you were already doing. I personally prefer your original one as the intent is clearer. but YMMV :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `left_outer_joins(subcategories: :products)`

Comment: Awesome! That is what I was looking for