# Rails 6.1 self referential has_many missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

[Rails 6.1 added](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34727) the `missing` method to find orphan records, but I'm struggling to apply it to a self referential `has_many`.

Consider this model:

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent_item, class_name: "Item"
  has_many :child_items, class_name: "Item", foreign_key: :parent_item_id
  has_many :approved_child_items, -> { approved }, class_name: "Item", foreign_key: :parent_item_id

  scope :approved, -> { where.not(approved_at: nil) }

  # This doesn't work:
  scope :no_child_items, -> { where.missing(:child_items) }
  # This doesn't work either:
  scope :no_approved_child_items, -> { where.missing(:approved_child_items) }
end
```

I want to find all the `Items` that don't have `child_items`.

How do I get the `no_child_items` and the `no_approved_child_items` scopes to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34727/files), it appears that the new method is simply a sugar for the old way (the one [with `left_joins`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34727)), but only its simple form. With self-referential relationships you can do

```
.left_joins(child_items: :items)
```

but this seems to not be supported in `missing`. So, it's likely you can't use `missing` for this. Use [`left_joins`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631514/activerecord-left-outer-joins-on-self-referencing-table) instead.

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but what is the full code for the left_join?

`left_joins(child_items: :items).where(child_items: {id: nil})` raises an `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError`

Comment: @sethherr: hm, that should have worked, I thought. I'll have to try it locally when I have a minute.

Comment: @sethherr you should be able to use `where.not(id: approved.select(:parent_item_id))`